# Is it good practice to use CRC32 for hashing Strings?

Tags: string, mongodb, hash, indexing, crc

Is it good practice to use CRC32 for hashing Strings? If not, what are better alternatives?

I have objects whose uniqueness is defined by 2 strings. I would like to add these objects to Mongo database, add calculated hash as an object's field, create index on that field and then search DB for object when I have the 2 strings (and can calculate the hash).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would work, but a CRC is not the best choice for hashing.  There are many hash functions that have been developed to be both fast and to minimize several different kinds of collision threats.

A very good example are the [CityHash set of algorithms](https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/).